# Empty a Div (toggle content) more than once

Tags: jquery, html

So, I'm trying to create a section on my site that will append a div, and then remove it when a button is clicked. As of right now I can add the div, and remove it fine. When I add it a second time it works perfectly, but it wont remove. It must be something simple I'm missing.

**HTML:**

```
<a id="addbtn" href="#">add</a>
<div id="stream"></div>
<a id="removebtn" href="#">remove</a>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function () {    

    $('a#addbtn').click(function () {
        var elems =
           '<div id="streamdiv">test content</div>';
        $('#stream').append(elems);
    });

    $('#removebtn').live('click', function () {
        $("#streamdiv").empty();
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r9XQu/500/)**

Comment: its because you empty it ... you dont actually remove it. You just remove the content, but you append the content again, thus you creating more than one instance of streamdiv. use `remove` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this work? https://jsfiddle.net/r9XQu/504/

```
$(function () {

    $('a#addbtn').click(function () {
        var elems =
            '<div class="streamdiv">test content</div>';
        $('#stream').append(elems);
    });

    $('a#removebtn').click(function () {
        $(".streamdiv:first").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, just had to change it to .remove() I figured it out before I saw this. I was just having a brain fart. haha

Answer (score 2):

If you want the entire stream to empty it should be `$("#stream").empty()`. Right now you're emptying the last div with the id `streamdiv`.

I should add that it's generally a bad practice to have multiple elements with the same ID. Use classes if you want a group of something to be accessible en masse.

Answer (score 1):

Changed .empty() to .remove() and that did the trick. Was just having a brain fart.

Comment: you should still change that from id to class, as you're only allowed to have 1 instance of each id

Comment: There will only ever be the once instance

Answer (score 0):

ID's have to be unique, but you're appending multiple items with the same id of `streamdiv`

try appending elements with the class of `streamdiv` instead

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r9XQu/501/)